# How do i get the password field to be equal to the password 123456 and for the button "ok" to work with it in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jpasswordfield

I want when I click the button "edit, add and update programme", The password field comes up and the button "ok" comes up. The ok button is supposed to call the displaytable() method which will display an editable table for the user to change.
how do i get the password to work

```
JButton passcode = new JButton("Edit, add or update programme");//creates button to display editable table
    passcode.setBounds(50,200,95,30);
        passcode.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //here
                Char[] password = "123456";
                JButton button = new JButton("OK");
                JPasswordField pf = new JPasswordField();
                button.addActionListener(e1 -> {

                    if(JPasswordField.getPassword.equals(password){
                        panel1.add(pf);
                        panel1.add(button); //TO HERE IM HAVING A PROBLEM WITH
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please do not shout at us. On the internet, all-caps is the equivalent of shouting. And you might want to add the "swing" tag.

Comment: thank you i didnt mean it in a bad way im sorry

Comment: Please describe what problem you get exactly. Do you mean you want to set the initial value as 123456 for password control, but you do not know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A better design would be to add these Components initially but disable them (setEnabled(false)). Anyway, to answer your question in the scenario you have, you should run your code on the UI thread, and revalidate and repaint after adding the new components

```
                if(JPasswordField.getPassword().equals(password){
                   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                        panel1.add(pf);
                        panel1.add(button); //TO HERE IM HAVING A PROBLEM WITH
                        panel1.validate();
                        panel1.repaint();
                     }
                  });
                }
```

Comment: @Avas if this has solved your problem please check the check mark next to the answer